# Trying to add minutes to HH:MM to 00:00 in Char(5) Field

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

I'm pretty new to SQL, someone has asked me for help and I'm trying to assist; I've installed SQL 2005 because this is the version they are running on.

My task:

They have a table called 'appTime' which is a char(5) type contains many times such as:
12:12
08:15
6:22
etc.

I have to increase the minutes in random increments between 1 minute to 15 minutes, I have no idea how to do it.

I've tried  to just randomly move the same number to another field eg:
UPDATE SET newTime = AppTime
and failed..

I'm not sure how to do it, I'm not sure why the time is even in a char type but I assume their software required it.

Any tips, help, assistance is GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I need to take the values in appTime (11:10, 11:20, 11:30, etc.) and update appTime2 with random 1 - 15 minute increments (11:14, 11:27, 11:31, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First make this string a time:

```
cast(apptime as time)
```

And here is how to create a random number from 1 to 15:

```
abs(checksum(newid())) % 15 + 1
```

And here is the random 1 to 15 minutes added to your time:

```
dateadd(minute, abs(checksum(newid())) % 15 + 1, cast(apptime as time))
```

(Yes the function is called `DATEADD`, but it also works on the `TIME` datatype. And 23:59 + 2 minutes results in 00:01 of course.)

Now we need to cast back to string. We need `CONVERT` for this in combination with the pre-defined format 108 which is 'hh:mi:ss'. (SQL Server doesn't feature user defined formats such as 'hh:mi' unfortunately, but as we cast to `CHAR(5)` only, the seconds get removed.)

```
convert(char(5), dateadd(minute, abs(checksum(newid())) % 15 + 1, cast(apptime as time)), 108)
```

The complete `UPDATE` statement:

```
update mytable
set newTime = convert(char(5), dateadd(minute, abs(checksum(newid())) % 15 + 1, cast(apptime as time)), 108);
```

In SQL Server 2005 the data type `TIME` is not available. Use `DATETIME` instead:

```
update mytable
set newTime = convert(char(5), dateadd(minute, abs(checksum(newid())) % 15 + 1, cast(apptime as datetime)), 108);
```

SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67c13/1.

Comment: I've just attempted, first and foremost thank you so much for taking the time to answer! I created a new 'newtime char(5) field and renamed apptime to appTime (which is where the data I want to change) when running the script I got Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type time is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type time is not a defined system type.
Any advice on how to resolve? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe Time isn't supported in SQL 2005? I was googling a bit to see if I can come up with an answer but no go :(

Comment: You are right; `TIME` was not available then. Use `DATETIME` instead. But I also had an error in my statement; I mistakenly casted from `TIME` to `TIME` instead of to `CHAR(5)`. Please try my updated answer.

Comment: The script provided this response: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value. (I hate this SQL version!!!)

Comment: I can only guess. Maybe replace `cast(apptime as datetime)` with `convert(datetime, apptime, 108)` or with `convert(datetime, apptime + ':00', 108)`? Or maybe replace `convert(char(5), ...)` with `left(convert(char(8), ...), 5)`? It's try and error. I don't work with SQL Server at all, so SQL fiddle is the only place where I try my queries and 2005 isn't featured there.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say thank you to Thorsten for his answer; I think I kind of figured out a caveman way of doing it; but it still is not efficient at all but at least it's something. I just went with:

Creating a new char(5) column called 'time'

*//' Grab AppTime where new time has no value and insert into 'time'*

UPDATE dbo.realMess SET time = appTime where newTime is null;

*//' Remove the ':' character making it a straight number*

UPDATE dbo.realMess SET time = replace(time,':','') where time is not null;

*//' Add a random number between 1 and 6 as a sample to increase the number*

UPDATE dbo.realMess SET time = time + ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 3) + 1;

*//' Add a starting 0 after adding a number removes the 0*

UPDATE dbo.realMess SET time = '0' + time WHERE LEN(time) < 4;

*//' Add the ':' back after the first 2 numbers, making it look like a time again*

UPDATE dbo.realMess SET time = stuff(time, 3, 0, ':');

*//' Update newTime with the new value of time where it is empty*

UPDATE dbo.tbAppLegs SET newTime = time where newTime is null;

This did the trick but not for any time after midnight military time, this is another headache to deal with later. This is literally the caveman way I've come up with. I hope I can re do this the proper way eventually; I've learned so much on this forum already; wanted to say thank you once more and perhaps my brain dead logic may actually help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, hoping that those really basic functions work in SQL 2005:

Ok I've reworked the whole thing to step by step change your appTime table (this is assuming the column with the dates in char is called "chardate":

First add a new column to store a real datetime

```
ALTER TABLE appTime
ADD newdate datetime;
```

Then add a column that will hold the new altered times

```
ALTER TABLE appTime
ADD newtime char(5);
```

Now we simply fill the newdate with 1.1.1900 (this will set the time to 00:00).

```
UPDATE appTime
SET newdate = '1900-1-1';
```

Now add the hours

```
UPDATE appTime
SET newdate = DATEADD(hh, CAST(LEFT(chardate,2) as int), newdate);
```

Now add the minutes

```
UPDATE appTime
SET newdate = DATEADD(mi, CAST(RIGHT(chardate,2) as int), newdate);
```

Now add the random 1-15 minutes

```
UPDATE appTime
SET newdate = DATEADD(mi, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID()) % 14) +1, newdate);
```

Now we cast the whole thing back to the char(5) column

```
UPDATE appTime
SET newtime =
  RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(hh,newdate) as varchar(2)),2)
 + ':'
 +RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(mi,newdate) as varchar(2)),2);
```

To show leading zeroes, you use the RIGHT() function. Otherwise 10:57 + 10 will get you 11:7 as string. Not what you want, I guess :)

If DATEPART fails, try using n instead of mi for minutes. I'm not 100% sure if 2005 supports both versions.

Comment: @tryingtofigurethingsout -  Due to my low rep I can only comment, but I see you're having trouble with the data types. Have you tried the solution I posted?

Comment: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value. <- my result, I'm not sure why this is so darn difficult and I have less than 24 hours to get it good.. Skype me if possible, maybe we can work together? ilan.patao

Comment: Ok, my altered code doesn't cast to datetime anymore, so hopefully this works.